# How to get name of students of three highest mark takers in each subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to get name of top 3 students in each subject.

For top 1 my query works

```
Result.group('subject').having('marks = MAX(marks)')
```

But how to get top 3?

Comment: what is your db engine?

Comment: There is a solution with window function and subquery. Does it fit you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `order` the records with `desc` of `marks` and `limit` it to three to get the top three students in each subject.

```
Result.group('subject').order('marks desc').limit(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution with postgres window function:

```
subscope = Result.select("*, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY subject ORDER BY marks DESC) AS pos"

Result.from(subscope).where("pos <= 3")
```